# Cannot use username variable inside scheduled task

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I would like to create a script that creates a scheduled task which removes everyday files from a specific folder, the script will be launched from intune. But the problem is that when I test the command on the task scheduler locally, it seems no to accept the username as variable.
Do you have any idea how to put username as variable in a powershell command in a task scheduler.
Here are the following commands.

Thank you folks.

```
$action=New-ScheduledTaskAction  -Execute "powershell.exe" '-Command "& {Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\$($env:USERNAME)\Documents\" *.mp4 -recurse | foreach { Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName -force } } '

$trigger=New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -daily -At 6pm 

$User= "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"

Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName "Delete files " -Description "Delete videos" -User $User -RunLevel Highest
```

I tested the script but it doesn't takes the username variable into account. Here is a screenshot from scheduled task :
[image]

UPDATE:
I resolved the issue by using @" "@ instead of single quotes. Here is the command :

```
$action=New-ScheduledTaskAction  -Execute "powershell.exe"  @"
-Command "& {Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\$($env:USERNAME)\Documents" *.txt -recurse | Remove-Item -force  }
"@
```

Comment: Which user? Windows is a multi-user OS :)

Comment: interpolation doesn't occur in single quotes.

Comment: This task will run on various machines, thats why I would like to specify username dynamically.

Comment: That should just be the current user profile: `$($Env:USERPROFILE)\Documents`

Comment: Yep it should be the current user profile, but the command works only if I use single quotes, but with single quotes i can’t use any variables

Comment: See [Passing arguments that contain quote characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7.2#passing-arguments-that-contain-quote-characters)

Comment: So you want to in effect hard-code the target user name based on the user that happens to be running the task-setup code in your question, across all the machines where the task will run?

Comment: As an aside: There's no reason to use `"& { ... }"` in order to invoke code passed to PowerShell's CLI via the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter - just use `"..."` directly. Older versions of the [CLI documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) erroneously suggested that `& { ... }` is required, but this has since been corrected.

Answer (score 2):

You've placed the the command in single quotes whereas powershell won't interpolate the variable reference. Swapping the quotes should fix your problem.

```
$task = @{
    Action   = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "powershell.exe" "-Command '&{Get-ChildItem -Path ""C:\Users\$($env:USERNAME)\Documents\"" *.mp4 -recurse | Remove-Item -Force -Verbose} *>&1 | Out-File ""C:\Log.txt"" -Append'"
    Trigger  = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -daily -At 6pm 
    User     = "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"
    TaskName = 'Delete Files'
    Description = 'Delete Videos'
    RunLevel    = 'Highest'
}

Register-ScheduledTask @task
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your quick response.
With your command, I could create the scheduled task, however when I execute it, it doesn't remove the files as expected. I think we should keep a thing quote before -Command ?, because with simple quotes and hard coded username it works, what do you think ?

Comment: @harris93. a thing quote? I'm not sure what you're referring to. I would add some logging to see why it's not deleting the files.

Comment: simple quote* sorry

Comment: Is there a way to add logging please, because the native ones with task scheduler are not helping much.

Comment: @harris93, use the new edited code. Will output all verbose/errors messages to `C:\log.txt`.

Comment: I tested the new code, it doesn’t write anything into the log file, perhaps any permission issue as it should write in the C:\ directory

Comment: @Metzli_Tonaltzintli, nice name!

Comment: @harris93 are you running this script in an elevated prompt?

Comment: @Metzli_Tonaltzintli yes I'm running the script with admin rights

Comment: @harris93, I'm not sure.